# Import "mongoengine.queryset.visitor" could not be resolved flask

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have `flask_mongoengine` and `mongoengine` in my `requirement.txt`. I ran `make install` but in `VS code` when I import from `mongoengine.queryset.visitor import Q` an orange line underlines it and hovering the line gives the reason  `Import "mongoengine.queryset.visitor" could not be resolved`. But I already mentioned that I have this package install in my flask app. Attached are the screenshots of my **requirement.txt** and import line errors.

[image: requirement.txt]

[image: Error on import line at top]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please select the correct interpreter:

1. Use shortcuts "Ctrl+shift+P"
2. Type "Python: Select Interpreter"

You can refer to these two issue on github for more information.

- https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/2400
- https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/885